# Необычная инициализация массива

Tags: c, массивы, инициализация

```
enum http_status {
    HTTP_OK = 200,
    HTTP_NOT_FOUND = 404,
    HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED = 405,
    HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR = 501,
};

static const char *status2str(enum http_status status)
{
    const char *strings[] = {
        [HTTP_OK] = "Ok",
        [HTTP_NOT_FOUND] = "Not found",
        [HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED] = "Method not allowed",
        [HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR] = "Internal server error",
    };
    return strings[status];
}
```

В функцию поступает число, как я получаю на выходе указатель на строку? Вот поступает число 200 в эту функцию, на выходе получаю указатель на строку `"Ok"`. Не могу понять как это работает. Как работает такое обращение к массиву?

Что делает эта запись `[HTTP_OK] = "Ok"`, что я могу обратиться к ней не по индексам, как привык делать, а по значению. Своего рода словарь получается.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Такая инициализация массивов разрешена начиная с C99. Выражение `[HTTP_OK]` называется *designator*. Элемент массива с индексом `HTTP_OK` будет хранить строковой литерал `"Ok"`, элемент с индексом `HTTP_NOT_FOUND` — строковой литерал `"Not found"` и так далее. Неинициализированные элементы будут иметь значение `NULL`:

```
strings = {
      0  NULL,
    ...  NULL,
    200  HTTP_OK,
    201  NULL,
    ...  NULL,
    404  HTTP_NOT_FOUND,
    405  HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED,
    406  NULL,
    ...  NULL,
    501  HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
}
```

Константа `HTTP_OK` и другие — это т. н. *константы перечисления* (англ. *enumeration constants*) — обычные числа типа `int`, поэтому когда мы пишем `strings[HTTP_OK]`, то обращаемся к элементу с индексом 200. Все вот так просто.

Answer (score 1):

Тут обращаешься к массиву по индексу, просто этот массив имеет значения только в индексах 200,404,405,501, а в остальных NULL(но я бы не был уверен что там всегда NULL)

Comment: Да, можно быть уверенным что остальные элементы массива - NULL. Стандарт C это гарантирует при частичной инициализации:

**C99 Standard 6.7.8.21**
If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.